# ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, nft

I have a nftToken Contract that mints token to msg.sender, then I have a function in a market contract that transfers the nft from owner to market contract. However, I am getting an error that says: ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved.

here is my nftContract (nft) function snippet:

```
function createToken(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint) {
  _tokenIds.increment();
  uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();

  _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
  _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
  setApprovalForAll(contractAddress, true);
  return newItemId;
}
```

here is my market code (stripeMarket Contract) function snippet:

```
function createItem(
    address nftContract,
    uint256 tokenId
    ) public payable{
     address _owner = IERC721(nftContract).ownerOf(tokenId);
     IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(_owner, address(this),tokenId);
      IERC721(nftContract).approve(address(this),tokenId);    
}
```

and here I am trying to call it from the frontend with web3:

```
const getItems=async()=>{
      await contracts.nft.methods.createToken("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nYxGhQYi0s4/maxresdefault.jpg").send({from: accounts[0]});
      const owners = await contracts.nft.methods.ownerOf(1).call({from:accounts[0]});
      await contracts.stripeMarket.methods.createItem(contracts.nft._address,1).send({from: {owners}}); 
}
```

But I am getting the error:

> ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When the `nftContract` executes the `setApprovalForAll(contractAddress, true)`, it allows the `contractAddress` (the Market contract) to operate **all of the `nftContract`'s tokens**.

But the newly minted token is owned by the `msg.sender` - **not by the `nftContract`**. So the approval does not apply to this token.

---

Depending on your use case, you can

1. Mint the new token to the `nftContract` (instead of the `msg.sender`) so that the Market contract is allowed to operate it. Or mint it to the Market contract directly.

   ```
   // the owner is the `nftContract`
   _mint(address(this), newItemId);

   // the Market contract is allowed to operate the `nftContract`'s tokens
   setApprovalForAll(contractAddress, true);
   ```
2. Have the `msg.sender` (the token owner) execute `approve(marketAddress, tokenId)` on the `nftContract` before executing the `createItem()`.

   This will give the Market contract approval to operate this particular token owned by the `msg.sender`. (Assuming it's the same address as the `_owner` - otherwise it will fail.)

Comment: That's happening also for me. But in my use case, when I mint the token, I need to transfer it to the user, not the market place. Actually there isn't a marketplace. How can this be implemented?. Thanks!

Comment: @nacho It depends on your specific code setup, so I'd suggest posting a separate question with minimal reproducible example. But as a general answer - the `transferFrom()` function accepts the recipient as the second argument. So you might need to pass the user address as the second argument there.