# Transfer from unknown account: revert ERC721: caller is not token owner or approved

Tags: solidity, erc721

I'm trying to implement a functionality in my smart contract in which a token owner (ERC721) transfers that token to a buyer. The buyer is the one that makes the call, after paying the requested amount. There is no marketplace involved. So I can't implement
[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69302320/erc721-transfer-caller-is-not-owner-nor-approved). After a user from any account wants to buy the token, I get this error:

> revert ERC721: caller is not token owner or approved.

Here is the code:

```
 function buyShirtNFT(uint256 _tokenId) public  payable 
  {
    require(tokenIdToShirtInfo[_tokenId].price > 0, "The NFT should be up for sale");

    uint256 cost = tokenIdToShirtInfo[_tokenId].price;
    
    address ownerAddress = ownerOf(_tokenId); 
    
    require(msg.value > cost, "You need to have enough Ether");
    transferFrom(ownerAddress, msg.sender, _tokenId);
    
    address payable ownerAddressPayable = _make_payable(ownerAddress); // We need to make this conversion to be able to use transfer() function to transfer ethers
    ownerAddressPayable.transfer(cost);
    if(msg.value > cost) 
    {
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value - cost);
    }
  }
```

Is there any way to solve this, or how can I implement my solution?.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error message `ERC721: caller is not token owner or approved` is displayed in your situation because the buyer (the person who calls the `buyShirtNFT` function) is neither the owner nor an authorized operator.

You can read more about the `ERC721` standard here:

[https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc721#:~:text=ERC721%20is%20a%20standard%20for,across%20a%20number%20of%20contracts](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc721#:%7E:text=ERC721%20is%20a%20standard%20for,across%20a%20number%20of%20contracts).